# How to Create a Dropdown List Hyperlink without the GO button?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I just want to create a dropdown list whenever I choose a new value inside it will take me to a new webpage. I don't want to let user to click "GO" button to go to the page. Just on select and call the action. How can I do such ?

```
<form>
<p align="center"><b>Select a Site </b>
<select id="setit" style="color: #0000FF" size="1" name="test">
<option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="http://www.altavista.com">AltaVista</option>
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
     <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option></select>
     <input type="button" value="Go"
onclick="window.open(setit.options[setit.selectedIndex].value)">
</p></form>
```

Here for example, this will have the GO button and need to click the GO in order to go to the new page. I don't want the GO button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use onchange event:

```
<select onchange="window.open(this.value,'','');">
....
</select>
```

Comment: Note that this will fail epically if the user has Javascript turned off, so you should have a "Go" button by default and hide it with JS.

Comment: +1 Better than mine, and heed Chucks Call. Don't want users unable to navigate.

Comment: Of course if javascript is disabled, even if you have a go button this doesn't make sense from the client side, you cannot open a link to a new window. For purposes of working on both scenarios independent of javascript I suggest to use links (anchors) for this to work.

Comment: Do not use <select> tag use <a> tag instead if you want them to work independently with javascript

Answer (score 0):

As fas as I understood - you simply have to handle onchange event for select tag.
Just move your onclick handler there.

Answer (score 0):

Put for your onclick

```
<input type="button" value="Go "onclick="document.location = this.value">
```

I use this one a lot and should work well

(Everyone else seams to be giving you onchange and say don't use javascript, but if the browser a person is using doesn't support javascript then tough shit because there not using chrome or another leading browser)